# How to correctly get the weights using spark for synthetic dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I'm doing LogisticRegressionWithSGD on spark for synthetic dataset. I've calculated the error on matlab using vanilla gradient descent and on R which is ~5%. I got similar weight that was used in the model that I used to generate y. The dataset was generated using [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46525/162487) example.

While I am able to get very close error rate at the end with different stepsize tuning, the weights for individual feature isn't the same. In fact, it varies a lot. I tried LBFGS for spark and it's able to predict both error and weight correctly in few iterations. My problem is with logistic regression with SGD on spark.

The weight I'm getting:

```
[0.466521045342,0.699614292387,0.932673108363,0.464446310304,0.231458578991,0.464372487994,0.700369689073,0.928407671516,0.467131704168,0.231629845549,0.46465456877,0.700207596219,0.935570594833,0.465697758292,0.230127949916]
```

The weight I want:

```
[2,3,4,2,1,2,3,4,2,1,2,3,4,2,1]
```

Intercept I'm getting: `0.2638102010832128`
Intercept I want: `1`

Q.1. Is it the problem with synthetic dataset. I have tried tuning with minBatchFraction, stepSize, iteration and intercept. I couldn't get it right.

Q.2. Why is spark giving me this weird weights? Would it be wrong to expect similar weights from Spark's model?

Please let me know if extra details is needed to answer my question.

Comment: Why do you expect rounded integer weights ? At least I can say that is not a common case. Second, Machine Learning doesn't guarentee to give weights you want, they are an output for training algorithm.

Comment: I'm expecting the algorithm to learn the weights. It doesn't have to be rounded integer but something close. Also, I'm expecting that because of the way synthetic dataset was created. I might be wrong but since I was able to get the weights very close to my expected ones on Matlab and R, I was trying to get the same from spark's algorithm as well.

Comment: Ah I see, one thing maybe you should be careful is SGD (stochastic Gradient Decent) which involves some randomness.

Comment: And still it actually did, your weights are normalized between 0 and 1, while expected max value is for, multiply everything you got from SGD with 4, you can see the correlation even for intercept value

Comment: Gosh, I think you're right. It really makes sense that way. I didn't notice it in the documentation.Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped, I am adding it as answer so further interaction wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering why the weights get normalized for LogisticRegressionWithSGD but it doesn't happen for LBFGS. I didn't find anything in the documentation that mentions that they're normalizing.

Comment: Hi, I think that can be another question. Maybe someone from spark community also helps, normally it should act in a standard way

Comment: I asked another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422875/why-does-my-weights-get-normalized-when-i-perform-logistic-regression-with-sgd-i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It  actually did converge, your weights are normalized between 0 and 1, while expected max value is for, multiply everything you got from SGD with 4, you can see the correlation even for intercept value.