# Why does my weights get normalized when I perform Logistic Regression With SGD in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, logistic-regression

I recently asked a question being confused about the weights I was receiving for the synthetic dataset I created. The answer I received was that the weights are being normalized. You can look at the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377796/how-to-correctly-get-the-weights-using-spark-for-synthetic-dataset). I'm wondering why LogisticRegressionWithSGD gives normalized weights whereas everything is fine in case of LBFGS in the same spark implementation. Is it possible that the weights weren't converging after all?

Weights I'm getting

```
[0.466521045342,0.699614292387,0.932673108363,0.464446310304,0.231458578991,0.464372487994,0.700369689073,0.928407671516,0.467131704168,0.231629845549,0.46465456877,0.700207596219,0.935570594833,0.465697758292,0.230127949916]
```

Weights I'm expecting ~

```
[2,3,4,2,1,2,3,4,2,1,2,3,4,2,1]
```

Comment: Without experience with this lib: looks like inconsistent design. SGD should always be used on normalized data (google it if you don't know why). So this lib seems to do it for you, and don't transform back. Not sure what's happening in the lbfgs-case, if they are normalizing or not, but lbfgs should be much more resilient to non-normalized data (as 2. order information is used).

Comment: Since the data was generated synthetically (I've linked to it on the earlier post), I think input has no problem with normalization but I see your point.